# Publishing ReadyToRun framework-dependent lambda with --no-build

Tags: .net-core, build

I've been working on our build pipeline for AWS Lambdas and wanted to add the ReadyToRun feature to reduce startup times. I noticed that in order to complete the publishing step, I needed to remove the `--no-build` flag. This rebuild step seems to run fairly quickly, so it's not a problem, but I'm curious as to why exactly it's needed.

This doesn't seem to be documented anywhere, and without it the `runtimeconfig.json` isn't compatible with a framework-dependent deployment. So basically `--no-build` is not compatible with `--no-self-contained`.

For context, we build in a custom Alipne-based container with the latest .net core 3.1 SDK and some other internal tools. The restore/build step runs first so we can then run all the tests and finally zip up the distributable package which is picked up by the rest of the CI pipeline. Everything after that first step carries the `--no-build` flag, except now for the `dotnet publish` step.

The commands boil down to basically this:

```sh
dotnet build --configuration Release --runtime linux-x64 # also takes care of the restore step
dotnet test --no-build # with some filters and coverage targets
dotnet publish --configuration Release --runtime linux-x64 --no-self-contained --framework "netcoreapp3.1" /p:ReadyToRun=true /p:GenerateRuntimeConfigurationFiles=true
```